# Endowing an abelian group with a metric.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory, metric-spaces

I solved the following exercise, which is not hard:

> Let $G$ be an additive abelian group, such that exists $f: G \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
>
> - $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.
> - $f(x) = f(-x)$.
> - $f(x + y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$, for all $x,y \in G$.
>
> Give an example of such a group and function, and prove that $d: G \times G \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $d(x,y) = f(x-y)$ is a metric on $G$.

Since I'm not a creative person, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $f: \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(0) = 0 $ and $f(1) = 1 $ works as an example. And proving that $d$ is a metric is straightforward.

My question is: is it always possible to define such a function $f$ satisfying these conditions? Also, I noticed that the function in my example induced the discrete metric (maybe because it is a sort of identity?). If it is not possible, is there a nice way to find conditions on the group that makes it possible?

---

In the comments, showed up another question, more interesting: if we consider a topological group, can we find a *continuous* function in the above conditions?

Comment: For any $G$ it seems to suffice to generalize your example by defining $f(0) = 0$ and $f(g) = 1$ for all $g \neq 0$.

Comment: Well, you're right, it does seems to work. But it's quite a trivial example, if you think about it haha

Comment: Perhaps it is more interesting to ask for an abelian topological group whether one can always choose $f$ continuous. Certainly it is possible to do this for connected abelian Lie groups.

Comment: I didn't even thought this far, this exercise was in a quite basic book, and happened to get me thinking. Perhaps my question has too much potential for good answers, to die with such a simple example. I would make your suggestion an edit here. Can I?

Comment: f is a norm on G and is imposed on a set so that you can talk about notions of "nearness" - in particular, it induces a metric. Different norms on the same set induce different notions of nearness.

Comment: But what would be a norm on a group? I would have to take a field and make $G$ a vector space, no?

Comment: @IvoTerek Yes, you're welcome to do so, but you're also welcome to post it as a new question.

Comment: Since no one posted anything as an answer yet, I'll use this question anyway, I don't want to flood the site (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a topology given, you can always choose $f = 1 - \chi_{\{0\}}$ as mentioned in [the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999747/endowing-an-abelian-group-with-a-metric#comment2043844_999747) by [Travis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155629/travis), and get the discrete metric.

Note that neither this, nor any of the following, requires commutativity. By changing the notation, the construction works identically for non-abelian groups.

If we have a topological group, things are more interesting. A necessary condition for the existence of a continuous $f\colon G \to [0,\infty)$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ is that $\{0\}$ is a $G_\delta$-set in $G$, since zero-sets of continuous functions are $G_\delta$-sets.

If $\{0\}$ is a $G_\delta$-set, then such an $f$ exists. If $\{0\} = \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty V_n$ with open sets $V_n$, then we can construct a sequence of symmetric ($U = -U$) open neighbourhoods $U_n$ of $0$ with $U_n \subset V_n$ and $U_{n+1} + U_{n+1} + U_{n+1} \subset U_n$ for all $n$. Now define

$$g(x) := \begin{cases}\qquad 1 &, x \notin U_1\\ \inf \{2^{-k} : x\in U_k \} &, x\in U_1\end{cases}$$

and

$$f(x) = \inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i) : n\in \mathbb{Z}^+, \bigl(\forall 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n\bigr)\bigl(x_i\in G\bigr), \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x \right\}.$$

By construction, $g\colon G \to [0,1]$ has $g(0) = 0$ and $g(-x) = g(x) > 0$ for all $x\in G\setminus\{0\}$, so $f\colon G\to [0,1]$ is symmetric and satisfies $f(0) = 0$. The triangle inequality $f(x+y) \leqslant f(x) + f(y)$ is easy to show. Further, we have

$$\frac{1}{2} g(x) \leqslant f(x) \leqslant g(x) \tag{$\ast$}$$

for all $x\in G$. The right inequality is immediate. For the left, we note that it is also clear for $x = 0$, and for $x\neq 0$ show that for any decomposition

$$x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

we have

$$\frac{1}{2}g(x) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)$$

by induction on the number $n$ of terms in the decomposition. The base case $n = 1$ is clear. So let $x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i$ and $s := \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} g(x_i)$. Since not all $x_i$ can be $0$, we have $s > 0$. If $s \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$, the left inequality in $(\ast)$ holds since $g(x) \leqslant 1$, so we need only consider $0 < s < \frac{1}{2}$. Let

$$m = \max \left\{ k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n+1,\, \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} g(x_i) \leqslant \frac{s}{2}\right\}.$$

Then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m g(x_i) > \frac{s}{2}$, and hence $\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{n+1} g(x_i) < \frac{s}{2}$. By the induction hypothesis we have

$$\frac{1}{2} g\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} x_i\right) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} g(x_i) \leqslant \frac{s}{2},\quad \frac{1}{2} g\left(\sum_{i=m+1}^{n+1} x_i\right) \leqslant \sum_{i=m+1}^{n+1} g(x_i) < \frac{s}{2},$$

and $\frac{1}{2} g(x_m) \leqslant \frac{s}{2}$ by definition of $s$. Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be minimal with $2^{-k} \leqslant s$ [since $s < \frac{1}{2}$, we have $k \geqslant 2$]. Then by definition of $g$, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} x_i,\, x_m,\, \sum_{i=m+1}^{n+1} x_i \in U_k$$

and thus

$$x = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i \in U_k + U_k + U_k \subset U_{k-1},$$

whence

$$\frac{1}{2}g(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} 2^{-(k-1)} = 2^{-k} \leqslant s.$$

From the right inequality in $(\ast)$, we obtain $f(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$, and $f^{-1}([0,2^{-k}]) \supset U_{k}$ shows that $f$ is continuous at $0$. From the triangle inequality we obtain

$$\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert \leqslant f(x-y),$$

which then shows the global continuity of $f$.

From the left inequality in $(\ast)$ we obtain $f^{-1}([0,2^{-k})) \subset U_{k}$, so the uniform structure induced by the metric $d(x,y) = f(x-y)$ coincides with the uniform structure generated by the sequence $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$, and the topology induced by the metric is coarser than the given topology [in general, strictly coarser, the constructed metric induces the given topology if $\{ U_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is a neighbourhood basis of $0$].

As a corollary, we note that a topological group is metrisable if and only if it is Hausdorff and first countable.

Comment: Awesome answer, and very instructive. Thanks for taking your time to answer!